# Свайп карточек как в Tinder

Tags: c#, winforms, swipe

Пожалуйста, помогите решить проблему в C# Windows Forms. В свою программу для тестирования пользователей мне нужно добавить возможность перелистывания (свайпа) карточек как в Tinder или других приложениях для знакомств.

Допустим, есть PictureBox. Пользователь нажимает на него курсором и уводит влево или вправо. Например, если он уводит его влево, то на определенном моменте PictureBox сам уходит влево и "скрывается" за пределами окна, при этом некоторая переменная увеличивается. Если вправо – то всё происходит аналогично, но переменная уменьшается. После "исчезания" карточки, плавно появляется новый PictureBox с новой картинкой. Но если пользователь недостаточно увёл карточку в сторону, то она возвращается обратно.

Как это можно организовать? У меня были некоторые идеи, но они не сработали. Пожалуйста, помогите, я чувствую что я близок к решению этой проблемы)

Comment: Так wpf или winforms?

Comment: @aepot, спасибо за ответ. В приоритете Windows Forms, но подойдёт решение и на WPF.